# Bank Hierarchy App- The field Savings.interest is never used

Tags: c#, class, hierarchy

hello iam creating an Account class that also has a Savings and a Checking, the account class is my base. ive run into a problem and im not sure how to fix... in my savings class when i try to write my account to the console im getting the error in my title. here is my code:

```
ACCOUNT CLASS (Base)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace accountApp
{
class Account
{
    private double _balance;

    public Account(double b)
    {
        Balance = b;
    }

    public double Balance
    {
        get { return _balance; }
        set
        {
            if (_balance > 0)
            {
                _balance = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Balance cannot be negative");
            }
        }






    }

    public  void Credit(double credit)
    {
        if (credit > 0)
        {
            _balance += credit;
        }


    }

    public void Debit(double debitAmount)
    {
        
        if (_balance - debitAmount >= 0)
        {
            _balance -= debitAmount;
            
        }
        else
        {
           
            Console.WriteLine("Debit is too high");


        }


    }



}
```

}

And here is my SAVINGS CLASS that is supposed to inherit from ACCOUNT:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace accountApp
{
class Savings : Account
{
    private double interest { get; }

    public Savings(double balance, double i) : base(balance)
    {
        Interest = i;


    }

    public double Interest { get; }

    public double CalculateInterest()
    {
        return Balance * Interest / 100;
    }
}
```

}

and so it runs but the output that i get is my else statement "Balance cannot be zero" since i guess the interest isnt being calculated.I realize this is probably a dumb question but it helps me sometimes to have another set of eyes

Comment: Please tag the correct language, this is definitely not C. But look at your setter, the problem is there. Running the code in a debugger line by line will help find these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in `Account` class in setting up `Balance`. Default value for double is 0.0, so when you're passing value to the Account constructor, let's say 2000 - it trying assing 2000 to `Balance`, but whats happens in yours setter.

You have condition to check if private property `_balance` is more than 0, but it's 0.

If you want assing only greater values than 0 to `_balance`, you should edit yours condition and check if `value` is more than 0, not `_balance`.

```
  public double Balance
    {
        get { return _balance; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
            {
                _balance = value;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Balance cannot be negative");
            }
        }
    }
```